# Prototype of method in java

Tags: java, c++

Is there a way to have prototypes in java, like in c++ you can do:

```
int proto(int x);
int main() {
   proto(5);
   return 0;
}

int proto(int x) {
   cout << x;  
   return 0;
}
```

Is there a way to do something like this in java, where you call a function that is physically below the function call.

Comment: I guess no because Java can do that without declaring prototype. https://ideone.com/1PzqeV

Comment: Now that I've thought past my snide comedy, I have to ask why? In my world prototypes are mostly just another line of code you can screw up and have to debug and can get out of synch, resulting in more debugging. But there must be a reason you want to do this and that has me thinking we've [hit an XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Rather than mocking the idea, why do you find this desirable? Perhaps we can offer a better alternative.

Comment: It's just that I learned to code in c++, and I just started java, so i thought that you needed something like a prototype for it to compile, I didn't know it worked without needing that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call a function defined below ***right away***:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    printHello();
}

public static void printHello() {
    System.out.println("Hello");
}
```

Comment: Oh snap I didn't know that, i should've probably tried that first